# A machinist is required to manufacture a circular metal disk with area $2000 cm^2$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, area

A machinist is required to manufacture a circular metal disk with area 2000 cm^2.

(a) What radius produces such a disk? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

**Answer; 25.23132522** <----- This answer is correct

(b) If the machinist is allowed an error tolerance of ±10 cm2 in the area of the disk, how close to the ideal radius in part (a) must the machinist control the radius? (Round your answers to four decimal places.)

**Answer; 25.16816786 cm    <   r   < 25.29432488 cm**

What value of ε is given?

**Answer;10 cm^2** <----- This answer is correct

What is the corresponding value of δ? (Round your answer to four decimal places.)

0.0632 cm <----- This answer is incorrect

I am confused about how 0.0632 is incorrect I did 
25.23132522 − 25.16816786 and rounded the answer. I look at sample problems and the way I solved it is the way it was solved.

Comment: Please use the link to format: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I suspect it's because you rounded up.  A $\delta$ value at the extreme you give would actually produce a disk outside the tolerance.  You have to round conservatively.

Comment: Thank you so very much @saulspatz I ended up getting the correct answer!